# Meteor login to server and login to local (app) when offline

Tags: cordova, meteor, meteor-accounts

I need to support the following situation within an app written in Meteor and deployed via cordova

When the client (device) is connected to the network:

- Login using the meteor accounts (so server side verification)

When the client (device) is not connected to the network:

- Login locally on the device.
- Have access to data that has previously
  been downloaded.
- Be able to modify at least a subset of that data: the exact use case is that there are two sets of records

  - 1. which
       are effectively read-only (still need to be able to read) - essentially a Task List and
  - 2. which are effectively new records created on the client - essentially a log by the worker of the activities taken place within that Task.

This is cornerstone functionality for the app and I would really appreciate feedback as to how to achieve this.

Comment: I'd take a look at https://atmospherejs.com/rtnpro/grounddb groundDB sounds to be doing what you want... I haven't explored it yet but it's in my bookmarks :)

Comment: @user2195559 Did you have any progress with this? Would be interesting.